# Load external library in java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, classloader

My scenario is the following:

I have a WebApp.war that is deployed to a servlet container. This WebApp.war contains in WEB-INF/lib the following libraries:

- lib_a.jar
- lib_b.jar

I have one other library, say lib_vendor.jar, that I cannot deploy within WebApp/WEB-INF/lib because of licensing issues so I let our customers to copy this library in tomcat/lib after application installation. But since lib_vendor.jar requires lib_a.jar and lib_b.jar that are loaded in the web application class loader, I cannot use lib_vendor.jar.

How can I load an external library (not in WEB-INF/lib) in the same classloader of a web application?

Comment: "because of licensing issues" try resolving the licensing issues ...

Comment: not sure but you can add the library in classpath. Not necessary to add it in `lib` directory.

Comment: NimChimpsky, it's not possible to resolve that licensing issues

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using Tomcat, you could leverage the [VirtualWebappLoader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/VirtualWebappLoader.html).

Add a `META-INF/context.xml` whith

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/somepath/myapp">
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
              virtualClasspath="/somedir/*.jar"/>
</Context>
```

Remember also that the virtualClasspath attribute must be a absolute path, as correctly stated in the comment below.

Comment: Just to confirm that this is a really correct answer, as [told here](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/how-to-use-VirtualWebappLoader-either-in-META-INF-context-xml-or-programmatically-on-startup-tp2017324p2017326.html), it must be an absolute dir. Relative like this doesn't work.