# Adding jars already specified as libs on the project into tomcats classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

When i create a web project in eclipse and on its build path i have added src folders, and in the libs i have added the spring3 jars as an external library. Now when I deploy this project on tomcat server (a separate servers project is created) the tomcat classpath has some tomcat jars and why can't adding the project itself to the classpath suffice ? Why do i need to add the jars in the project's lib folder on tomcats classpath ? Doesn't it seem cyclic, since the project already has its dependencies specified on its buildpath under libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

Question has some ambiguities "*since the project already has its dependencies specified on its buildpath under libraries ?*"

But I will try to answer certain parts of it.

Usually the server follow a certain structure of the application deployed.

for e.g. 
web.xml in WEB-INF ,or,
lib (folder for storing jars) in WEB-INF folder.

This holds even for simple standalone projects where adding a jar in eclipse classpath is not sufficient, you have to either update you MANIFEST.MF or use '-cp' arg to update classpath while running the jar.

Now I will try to answer you question in parts:

Adding external jars using eclipse, you will see the modifications in .classpath file of eclipse project, which holds meaning only to eclipse, but not to tomcat server.

There are two ways to add jars, but since you are trying to add spring3, which does not have licensing issues, you can package the same in your war file under, WEB-INF/lib folder.

or,
If you do not want to follow approach -1 go for approach -2:

[Load external library in java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704915/load-external-library-in-java-web-application)