# Where to place Solr logging jars so they are not loaded by other applications?

Tags: tomcat, solr, tomcat7

The [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging) recommends that the logging jars are placed in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. I have followed these instructions however these libraries are conflicting with another application that is deployed on the same server.

How can I configure Tomcat to load these libraries from another location so that they are only loaded by Solr? I would prefer not to alter the Solr war file if possible.

I am using Tomcat 7.0.47 and Solr 4.6.

Comment: Why don't you want to put those library inside the solr.war? They will [stop shipping a war in 5.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4792) anyway. So then you will need to package you own solr.war.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to keep any configuration information separate so that it is easier to upgrade, redeploy to another server, etc. But this may be the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this by adding a snippet to my context file. Here is my file:

```
<Context docBase="path_to_solr/example/solr/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
 <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="path_to_solr/example/solr" override="true" />
 <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/path_to_solr_libs;/path_to_solr_libs/*.jar"/>
</Context>
```

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706492/1291332).

Answer (score 0):

```
<solr.solr.home><collection>/lib/
```

In other words lib directory at the same level as conf/ directory of your solr core/collection.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as Solr loads the jars that are placed here after it has started. The logging jars are needed for Solr to start.